# Open kendo menu onClick using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Here is my code

```
  <ul kendo-menu k-orientation="horizontal" k-options="kendomenu">
                        <li ng-repeat="toplevel in UserMenu.TopLevels" class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem" >
                            <span class="k-link">
                                {{toplevel.name}}
                                <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span>
                            </span>
                            <ul class="k-group k-menu-group k-popup k-reset" role="menu" ng-repeat="level2 in toplevel.levels" >
                                <li class="k-item k-state-default" ng-repeat="view in level2.views"><span class="k-link" ng-click="addTab(view.name,getTemplate(view.link))">{{view.name}}</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

I want to open this LI on UL click

```
                                <li class="k-item k-state-default" ng-repeat="view in level2.views"><span class="k-link" ng-click="addTab(view.name,getTemplate(view.link))">{{view.name}}</span></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo Menu has a property which you can set to open the menu on click instead of Hover.

In your Controller create a property as

```
$scope.kendoMenuOptions = {
       openOnClick: true
    };
```

and then in the HTML set the options as:

```
k-options="kendoMenuOptions"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. its working , charrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssss